# Multiple SQL Searches - OR Command

Tags: php, sql

My users can search for an order by an address right now.  What I would like to do is let them be able to search with multiple criteria.  Let them search by address, city, state, etc etc.

I have tried using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$sql = ("SELECT order_number, sitestreet FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `sitestreet` LIKE '%$street%' OR `sitecity` LIKE '%$city%' AND `user` LIKE '$user'");

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I don't think it's reading the value in $user cause it displays all orders for all users.

How can I make it possible to search for an order using multiple serach values?

Thank you!

Comment: i think the like on user should be where user = 'user' instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your OR statements in parenthesis so it forms one top-level condition, the user is the other top-level condition:

```
$sql = '
  SELECT 
    `order_number`, 
    `sitestreet` 
  FROM  
    `PropertyInfo` 
  WHERE  
     (
        `sitestreet` LIKE "%'.$street.'%" OR 
        `sitecity` LIKE "%'.$city.'%"
     ) AND 
     `user` = '.$user;
```

Also note, you want a direct match to the `user` column, use `=` instead of `LIKE`.  I am assuming that `$user` is a numeric ID...

Answer (score 0):

How about trying like

```
$sql = ("SELECT order_number, sitestreet FROM PropertyInfo WHERE (sitestreet LIKE   
      '%$street%' OR sitecity LIKE '%$city%') AND user LIKE '$user'");
```

Answer (score 0):

AND has a higher order of precedence than OR (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html for details).  You need to wrap your OR statement in parentheses so it get evaluated as one statement, before the AND statement.

```
SELECT order_number, sitestreet 
FROM  `PropertyInfo` 
WHERE  (`sitestreet` LIKE '%$street%' OR `sitecity` LIKE '%$city%') 
AND `user` LIKE '$user'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = ("
  SELECT order_number, sitestreet 
  FROM  `PropertyInfo` 
  WHERE  (`sitestreet` LIKE '%$street%' 
    OR `sitecity` LIKE '%$city%') 
  AND `user` LIKE '$user'");
```

You should group the ORs together. The way it is written I believe it is reading it as 'if Street matches, ignore any other conditions (OR), otherwise both city and user must match.

Also G molvi's point is good, unless you're looking for a pattern match, go with `=`

HTH